# Android SeekBar Application - Unfortunately, project has stopped

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to Android dev and for my project, I am creating two seekbars. The first seekbar has a minimum of 50 and a maximum of 180 while the second seekbar has a minimum of 180 and a maximum of 400. I also added textview labels below each seekbar to show the current value of each. My code compiled fine without any errors and displayed fine on the Android emulator, but when I clicked on the slider to change the value of the seekbar, my app ended up crashing and saying, "Unfortunately, your project has stopped." Below is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.myname.projectname;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
    import android.R.*;
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements      OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        private SeekBar lowBar;
        private SeekBar highBar;
        private TextView lowtext;
        private TextView hightext;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           initializevariables();
           lowBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.lowbar);
           highBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.highbar);
           lowtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lowval);
           hightext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.highval);

           lowBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
           highBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

       }


       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is  present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();

       //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }

       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
       private void initializevariables(){
           lowBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.lowbar);
           highBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.highbar);
       }

       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
       {
           progress = 0;
           int lowbarmin = progress + 50;
           int highbarmin = progress + 180;
           lowtext.setText(lowbarmin);
           hightext.setText(highbarmin);
       }

       @Override
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

       }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText android:text="CGM Alarm System" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lowbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progress="0"
    android:max="180"/>

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/highbar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lowbar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lowbar"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/lowbar"
    android:progress="0"
    android:max="400"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="50"
    android:id="@+id/lowval"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lowbar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="180"
    android:id="@+id/highval"
    android:layout_below="@+id/highbar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myname.projectname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
         android:name="com.example.myname.projectname.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where is your logcat??post it.

Comment: Why you increase            int lowbarmin = progress + 50;
           int highbarmin = progress + 180; ???

Answer (score 0):

Your seekbar's minimum value is 50, you can not increase +50;

```
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
   {
       int lowbarmin = progress + 1;
       int highbarmin = progress + 1;
       lowtext.setText(lowbarmin);
       hightext.setText(highbarmin);
   }
```

Comment: Alright, I have finally figured out my error. It came from not converting lowbarmin and highbarmin to strings. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Crash is probably because of these lines :

```
lowtext.setText(lowbarmin);
hightext.setText(highbarmin);
```

When you do this and the value of lowbarmin and highbarmin are integers, android looks for string resources with those values as their resourceId and it cannot find one.

So what you instead want to do is, pass string values to setText() :

```
lowtext.setText(Integer.toString(lowbarmin));
hightext.setText(Integer.toString(highbarmin));
```